# Regular expression for day offset

Tags: java, regex, quartz-scheduler

I want to calculate time offset (number of day) base on user defined expression. The expression will support the following keywords:

1. `+` -> increments
2. `-` -> decrements
3. `D` -> day
4. `W` -> week
5. `M` -> month
6. `WD` -> working day (non-holiday from business calendar)

Example:

```
+3D means adding 3 days to the offset
-3D means reduce 3 day from the offset
+34M+3D means adding 34 months and 3 days to the offset
+3D+1WD  means adding 3 days and then add one extra working day.
```

The problem is I am not sure how to write a regular expression to process the string. Could anyone give me some example?

This is what I try so far, notice the second token is incorrect

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[+-]+([0-9]+)[WD|D|W|M]");
 Matcher m = p.matcher("+1D-2WD+3M");
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Results:

```
+1D
-2W
+3M
```

Comment: Can we see [what have you tried till now?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Did you try putting "java regular expression" into Google?  That's kind of what the term "research effort" in the upvote and downvote tooltips means.

Comment: Please see my updates

Comment: Because you didn't use the right regex : [WD|D|W|M] is a single character in the list WD|M literally (case sensitive).   the | inside [] is no more an "OR", but the charater | itself .

Comment: I've addedd working code example in my answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would go for

```
(([+-])(\d+)(WD|[DWM]))
```

[+-] : + or - symbol

\d+ : at least one digit

WD : WD

| : or

[DWM] : D or W or M

[Working example](https://regex101.com/r/dG5aX2/1)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(([+-])(\\d+)(WD|[DWM]))");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("+1D-2WD+3M");
        while(m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            // Splitted argument
            System.out.println("Operator : " +  m.group(2));
            System.out.println("Number : " +  m.group(3));
            System.out.println("Period : " +  m.group(4));

        }
```

Comment: Great  link to understand regex